# Copy every children of a group to another group?

Tags: kineticjs

I have to handle a lot of polygons, etc.
So what I intend to do is to "add" or "draw" a set of polygons to a "temporary" group, and then give these polygons to another group, and empty the temporary group.

So here is what I do:

where "tmp" and "fak" are Kinetic Groups

```
function frame(array,R,G,B,A){
        poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: array,
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            class: A
        });
        if(R!=null||G!=null||B!=null){
            poly.setFill('rgba('+R+','+G+','+B+',1)');
        } else {
            poly.setFill('rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        };
        tmp.add(poly);
    };
```

then here comes an object with functions that call the "frame" function

```
var parent={
    child1:function(R,G,B,A){
                    ...
        Left.light(R,G,B,A);
                    ...
        tmp.moveTo(fak);
        layer.add(fak);
            tmp.remove();
    },
    child2:function(R,G,B,A){}
}
```

the only problem with this solution is that moveTo function only links the content of "tmp" to "fak" and when I delete "tmp"  with tmp.remove(), I get nothing. Is there any way to give the children of tmp to fak and then empty tmp without losing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A more direct way of using a template is to use the `clone` method.**

- Create a template group with the elements you need (groupTemplate).
- When you need a copy...var groupFromTemplate = groupTemplate.clone.

You can even reset the cloned group's properties during the cloning process.

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LkFs9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

            $(stage.getContent()).on('click', function (event) {
                var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
                var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
                var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
                console.log(mouseX+"/"+mouseY);
            });


    var group1=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:30,
        y:30,
    });
    layer.add(group1);

    var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:10,
        y:10,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
    });
    group1.add(circle1);

    var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:25,
        y:25,
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
    });
    group1.add(circle2);

    var group2=group1.clone({
        x:100,
        y:40
    });
    layer.add(group2);

    layer.draw();







}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```